# Pine script callback

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to use callbacks in Pine Script? Something like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Callback")
callackCaller(callback) =>
    callback(0)
callbackFunction(value) =>
    value

callbackCaller(callbackFunction)

plot(close)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

There is no Function argument type in Pine so you cannot pass it as a function parameter.

When thinking about Pine's capabilities, aim a bit below Turbo Pascal to minimize the number of wtf/min.

Answer (score 0):

I am also curious about the answer to this question. The built-in function "request.security" already achieve similar functionality, but it seems that developers cannot implement it.

Comment: Do not add an aswer to say that you also have the same question